# C++, namespace best practice

Tags: c++, namespaces

My project is divided into modules and they all share a similar structure, instead of writing classes like `EntityHandler` and `InputHandler`, I'd like to use namespaces and do `Input::Handler` and `Entity::Handler`. Now this all seems good to me, but those namespaces are also nested inside one more namespace which also have a `Handler` class!

Some people said that this is bad practice and could be confusing, but as part of my style I never use the `using <namespace>;` keyword so it will always look explicit. Do you think this would be good practice, and if not can you tell me where this could come back to bite me down the line?

I'm sorry if this has been asked before, the places I looked didn't give good explanations as to why or why not to do this!

Comment: If the sole purpose of the namespaces is to name some classes by providing a prefix: Just don't.

Comment: well it's more of sharing class names for different modules in my project, for example I'd have Entity::Handler,Entity::Instance, Entity::Tags etc... each module gets a namespace and the same class names, can this go bad down the line?

Comment: Please comment on @MichaelUshakov s answer.

Answer (score -2):

I think it is better to fully qualify namespace without using because it allow to get rid of some mistakes when reading and/or compiling code. In many tutorials it is recommended to use fully qualify namespace i.e. void doSome (std::vector& data) in function declaration instead of placing using namespace std + doSome (vector& data) . It is good practice to fully qualify namespace because it allow to reduce type resolve ambiguity errors on a compilation stage. Consider following example:

```
class A {
private:
    Super::Handler* _handlerOne;
    Super::Entity::Handler* _handlerTwo;
};
```

It would be hard to do the same when you will be use using:

```
using namespace Super;
using namespace Super::Handler;

class A {
private:
    Handler* _handlerOne;  // What type compiler place here ??? , we don't know ...
    Handler* _handlerTwo;  // What type compiler place here ??? , we don't know ...
};
```

Less ambiguities - better code.

Comment: You could have been more constructive with this comment.  There is no need to be condescending.

Comment: My message was directed at another user who was acting up, and their comment is now deleted.

Comment: Oh, sorry, @paddy I did not understand

Comment: Ok, more diplomatic: Your answer doesn't even try to answer the question asked.

Comment: @Swordfish why do you think so. One more time: Question was: "why or why not to do this!" word this here means - use fully qualified namespaces i.e. A::B instead of using namespace A  + declare types just as B. I've demonstrated example where 2nd variant could lead to ambiguity for compiller and reduce code readability.

Comment: @MichaelUshakov The question is (read again!!) if it's ok to put those `Handler` in a namespace each or to name then `EntityHandler`, `InputHandler`, ...

Comment: @Swordfish, author of this post wrote that he already have project with simillar structure (thi is a fact), so there is no classes with names: EntityHandler, InputHandler instead of this he has a lot of Handler classes (So he is not asking about what to choose a) different class names or b) same names but in different namespaces). And question is about usage namespaces Input::Handler and Entity::Handler instead of using - using <namespace> and what it is better/worse choice;

Comment: *"but as part of my style I never use the using <namespace>; keyword so it will always look explicit."* – Go, read again. You're barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: wow this went kinda south, here lemme rephrase
I was doing a refactor and already had EntityHandler, InputHandler classes, as part of the refactor I thought about doing the namespace thing(without invoking the using keyword), my question was about whether this would be good practice(or rather acceptable practice), your answer,while not a bad one, glossed over the fact that I'll only be doing things as you did in the first example

Comment: @Cufox Then you should think about what gives a class prefix to you? Is it something significant (i.e. maybe it allows to easy understand role of you class in you app) if not you could easily remove it. Also it should be noted that many big and popular libraries like boost uses approach with full namespaces qualification.